# Facebook Pages — Authoritative List of Categories

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find out about a Facebook user's interests based on pages they like, etc. It would be useful to have the list of possible page categories. I have made a rough list based on the dropdown menus from the page creation form, but the values in this are slightly different to those returned by the Graph API (e.g. "Sports_teams" as opposed to "Sports team").

So, what I'd like to know is:

1. Where can I find a complete list of available categories, in the form that I'll see them when I query the Graph API?
2. Are these strings localised? If so, where can I find the en_GB ones?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Ross

BTW, my list of categories is:

```
19,Band
19,Musician
68,Restaurant
88,Film
89,TV Programme
91,Technology product/service
92,Financial Service
94,Fashion
108,Museum/attraction
109,Park
110,Travel
111,Hotel/B&amp;B/Hostel
112,Hotel/B&amp;B/Hostel
113,Travel service
114,Airline/Ship/Train Station
115,Convention or sports centre
116,Car Hire
117,Home living
121,Café
123,Health and beauty
124,Education
125,Event planning service
126,Banking and financial service
127,Technology and telecommunications service
129,Medical service
130,Home service
131,Car Dealer/Vehicle Service
132,Local business
133,Pharmaceutical
134,Pets
135,Professional service
136,Professional service
137,Property
138,Food &amp; drink
139,Supermarket
140,Automotive
141,Consumer product
142,Sports/athletics
143,Retail
144,Shop
145,Online shop
147,Religious organisation
148,Religious centre
149,Library/Public Building
150,Government
151,Politician
152,Non-profit
154,Game
156,Sports team
157,Actor
158,Model
159,Comedian
160,Visual artist
161,Writer
162,Critic
163,Public figure
164,Club
165,Pub/bar
167,Website
169,Athlete
170,Communications
176,Products
349,Government Official
```

Answer (score 24):

I took the time to document a script that can grab the above data in JSON format. For anyone interested, check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bloudermilk/2173940). The list of categories that I got as of March 23, 2012 is:

```
{
  "1105": "Movie",
  "1108": "Producer",
  "1109": "Writer",
  "1112": "TV/Movie Award",
  "1113": "Fictional Character",
  "1114": "Movie Character",
  "1200": "Album",
  "1201": "Song",
  "1207": "Music Video",
  "1208": "Concert Tour",
  "1210": "Radio Station",
  "1211": "Record Label",
  "1212": "Music Award",
  "1213": "Music Chart",
  "1300": "Book",
  "1301": "Author",
  "1307": "Magazine",
  "1309": "Book Series",
  "1400": "TV Show",
  "1402": "TV Network",
  "1404": "TV Channel",
  "1600": "Athlete",
  "1601": "Artist",
  "1602": "Public Figure",
  "1604": "Journalist",
  "1605": "News Personality",
  "1606": "Chef",
  "1607": "Lawyer",
  "1610": "Comedian",
  "1613": "Teacher",
  "1614": "Dancer",
  "1617": "Entrepreneur",
  "1700": "Politician",
  "1701": "Government Official",
  "1800": "Sports League",
  "1801": "Sports Team",
  "1802": "Coach",
  "1803": "Amateur Sport Team",
  "1804": "School Sports Team",
  "2200": "Company",
  "2201": "Product/Service",
  "2202": "Website",
  "2205": "Cars",
  "2206": "Bags/Luggage",
  "2208": "Camera/Photo",
  "2209": "Clothing (Brand)",
  "2210": "Computers (Brand)",
  "2211": "Software",
  "2213": "Electronics",
  "2214": "Health/Beauty",
  "2216": "Building Materials",
  "2217": "Commercial Equipment",
  "2219": "Furniture",
  "2220": "Household Supplies",
  "2222": "Patio/Garden",
  "2223": "Tools/Equipment",
  "2224": "Wine/Spirits",
  "2226": "Jewelry/Watches",
  "2230": "Pet Supplies",
  "2231": "Outdoor &amp; Sporting Goods Company",
  "2232": "Baby Goods/Kids Goods",
  "2233": "Media/News Company",
  "2234": "Finance Company",
  "2235": "Non-Governmental Organization (NGO)",
  "2236": "Insurance Company",
  "2238": "Energy Company",
  "2239": "Retail Company",
  "2240": "Automotive Company",
  "2241": "Industrial Company",
  "2243": "Medical Company",
  "2244": "Aerospace Company",
  "2245": "Mining Company",
  "2246": "Agriculture Company",
  "2248": "Consulting Agency",
  "2249": "Legal Company",
  "2250": "Education",
  "2252": "Food &amp; Beverage Company",
  "2253": "Telecommunication Company",
  "2255": "Computer Company",
  "2256": "Internet Company",
  "2257": "Tobacco Company",
  "2258": "Travel Company",
  "2262": "Vitamins/Supplements",
  "2263": "Pharmaceuticals",
  "2265": "Phone/Tablet",
  "2300": "Games/Toys",
  "2301": "App Page",
  "2303": "Board Game",
  "2500": "Local Business",
  "2505": "Transit Stop",
  "2601": "School",
  "2602": "College &amp; University",
  "2603": "Non-Profit Organization",
  "2606": "Cause",
  "2618": "Political Party",
  "2632": "Pet",
  "2637": "Middle School",
  "1757592557789532": "Advertising/Marketing Service",
  "1574325646194878": "Agriculture",
  "128966563840349": "Airport",
  "1086422341396773": "Apparel",
  "133436743388217": "Arts &amp; Entertainment",
  "180410821995109": "Automotive",
  "125178521242121": "Aviation",
  "110290705711626": "Bar",
  "139225689474222": "Beauty",
  "197048876974331": "Book Store",
  "1728747447366202": "Business",
  "187133811318958": "Business Service",
  "917138848432787": "Casino &amp; Gaming",
  "557045641143373": "Design",
  "188234584533149": "Doctor",
  "806240166180298": "Environmental Service",
  "193705277324704": "Event Planning Service",
  "871941916244102": "Fashion",
  "1022050661163852": "Finance",
  "150108431712141": "Grocery Store",
  "108427109235243": "Home Improvement",
  "1025733874177680": "Home Improvement Service",
  "1730236023904374": "Home Service",
  "133152263416981": "Hospital/Clinic",
  "164243073639257": "Hotel",
  "505091123022329": "Hotel &amp; Lodging",
  "209889829023118": "Landmark &amp; Historical Place",
  "241113486274430": "Legal",
  "169896676390222": "Library",
  "1758418281071392": "Local Service",
  "1422088814483501": "Marine",
  "145118935550090": "Medical &amp; Health",
  "192511100766680": "Movie Theater",
  "179943432047564": "Performance &amp; Sports Venue",
  "144982405562750": "Pet Service",
  "147714868971098": "Public Services &amp; Government",
  "198327773511962": "Real Estate",
  "186982054657561": "Recreation &amp; Fitness",
  "187714557925874": "Religious Organization",
  "273819889375819": "Restaurant",
  "200600219953504": "Shopping/Retail",
  "109976259083543": "Stadium, Arena &amp; Sports Venue",
  "124861974254366": "Tour Agency",
  "145887745471348": "Train Station",
  "150148928375567": "Biotechnology Company",
  "184395321600410": "Cargo &amp; Freight Company",
  "191334714243008": "Chemical Company",
  "152880021441864": "Community Organization",
  "170968163319233": "Community Service",
  "140234236045713": "Elementary School",
  "161422927240513": "Government Organization",
  "110152272401235": "High School",
  "192775991124365": "Labor Union",
  "198503866828628": "Organization",
  "373543049350668": "Political Organization",
  "180551801986954": "Preschool",
  "297544187300691": "Science &amp; Engineering",
  "150060378385891": "Appliances",
  "1605186416478696": "Brand",
  "192647794097278": "Home Decor",
  "132852590115660": "Kitchen/Cooking",
  "110249975723427": "Office Supplies",
  "211579738882707": "Video Game",
  "1602034176774683": "Actor",
  "792007097567368": "Band",
  "361282040719868": "Blogger",
  "1784467105117322": "Fashion Model",
  "502966423232592": "Film Director",
  "301500100194179": "Fitness Model",
  "1720316034885300": "Motivational Speaker",
  "1335670856447673": "Musician",
  "181475575221097": "Photographer",
  "842783295865930": "Political Candidate",
  "494338820719492": "Scientist",
  "596582600510249": "Festival",
  "856055631167537": "Literary Arts",
  "370369022981015": "Movie/Television Studio",
  "756092301147942": "Performance Art",
  "1758092431143387": "Performing Arts",
  "627651640670228": "Podcast",
  "943469559038367": "Theatrical Play",
  "1784293938474260": "Theatrical Productions"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the instructions in the gist and it worked perfectly!

Comment: When I use FQL to extract page categories, this doesn't seem to work .. I see stuff like: "Fine Dining Restaurant", "American Restaurant", "Japanese Restaurant", "Coffeeshop" etc. Any ideas?

Comment: hi, FYI, the jQuerify technique doesn't work anymore: I get an error: "Refused to load the script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.akamaihd.net *.atlassolutions.com blob: chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl".
getScript @ VM180:1(anonymous function) @ VM180:1(anonymous function) @ VM180:1"

Answer (score 9):

I gathered a random sample of 105k pages using Facebook's search api and got 197 page categories, way more than the 147 that appear on the "create page" webpage. This is the list:

```
Actor/director
Aerospace/defense
Airport
Album
Amateur sports team
Anatomical structure
Animal
Animal breed
App
App page
Appliances
Artist
Arts/entertainment/nightlife
Arts/humanities website
Athlete
Attractions/things to do
Author
Automobiles and parts
Automotive
Baby goods/kids goods
Bags/luggage
Bank/financial institution
Bank/financial services
Bar
Biotechnology
Book
Book genre
Book store
Building materials
Business person
Business services
Business/economy website
Camera/photo
Cars
Cause
Chef
Chemicals
Church/religious organization
City
Clothing
Club
Coach
Color
Comedian
Commercial equipment
Community
Community organization
Community/government
Company
Computers
Computers/internet website
Computers/technology
Concert tour
Concert venue
Consulting/business services
Continent
Country
Dancer
Degree
Diseases
Doctor
Drink
Drugs
Editor
Education
Education website
Electronics
Energy/utility
Engineering/construction
Entertainer
Entertainment website
Episode
Event planning/event services
Farming/agriculture
Fictional character
Field of study
Food
Food/beverages
Food/grocery
Furniture
Games/toys
Government official
Government organization
Government website
Health/beauty
Health/medical/pharmaceuticals
Health/medical/pharmacy
Health/wellness website
Home decor
Home improvement
Home/garden website
Hospital/clinic
Hotel
Household supplies
Industrials
Insurance company
Interest
Internet/software
Jewelry/watches
Journalist
Kitchen/cooking
Landmark
Language
Lawyer
Legal/law
Library
Local business
Local/travel website
Magazine
Media/news/publishing
Medical procedure
Mining/materials
Monarch
Movie
Movie general
Movie genre
Movie theater
Movies/music
Museum/art gallery
Music
Music award
Music chart
Music video
Musical genre
Musical instrument
Musician/band
Neighborhood
News personality
News/media website
Non-governmental organization (ngo)
Non-profit organization
Office supplies
Organization
Other
Outdoor gear/sporting goods
Patio/garden
Personal blog
Personal website
Pet services
Pet supplies
Playlist
Political ideology
Political organization
Political party
Politician
Producer
Product/service
Professional services
Professional sports team
Public figure
Public places
Publisher
Radio station
Real estate
Record label
Recreation/sports website
Reference website
Regional website
Religion
Restaurant/cafe
Retail and consumer merchandise
School
School sports team
Science website
Shopping/retail
Small business
Society/culture website
Software
Song
Spas/beauty/personal care
Sport
Sports league
Sports venue
Sports/recreation/activities
State/province/region
Studio
Teacher
Teens/kids website
Telecommunication
Tools/equipment
Tours/sightseeing
Transit stop
Transport/freight
Transportation
Travel/leisure
Tv
Tv channel
Tv genre
Tv network
Tv show
Tv/movie award
University
Vitamins/supplements
Website
Wine/spirits
Work position
Writer
```

In case you're wondering, this is the code I used (python):

```
categories = set()
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
for i in xrange(20):
    for j in xrange(10):
        q = chr(97+i)+chr(97+j)
        for r in graph.request("search", {"q": q, "type":"page", "limit": 1000})["data"]:
            categories.add(str(r["category"]))
```

Basically perform a bunch of random 2 character long queries and gather the resulting pages. It works!

Answer (score 7):

As of Dec-2014 i got the following list with search API (Graph API version v2.2)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

> Returns a list of possible place Page topics and their IDs. Use with
>   topic_filter=all parameter to get the full list.

```
search?type=placetopic&topic_filter=all

 "Abortion Services"
 "Accessories Store"
 "Accountant"
 "Active Life"
 "Acupuncture"
 "Addiction Resources"
 "Admissions Training"
 "Adoption Service"
 "Adult Education"
 "Adult Entertainment"
 "Advertising Agency"
 "Advertising Service"
 "Afghani Restaurant"
 "African Methodist Episcopal Church"
 "African Restaurant"
 "Agricultural Service"
 "AIDS Resources"
 "Airline Industry Services"
 "Airline"
 "Airport Lounge"
 "Airport Shuttle"
 "Airport Terminal"
 "Airport"
 "Allergist"
 "Allergy Doctor"
 "Alternative & Holistic Health"
 "Ambulance & Rescue"
 "American Restaurant"
 "Amusement Park Ride"
 "Amusement"
 "Anglican Church"
 "Animal Shelter"
 "Antique Store"
 "Antiques & Vintage"
 "Apartment & Condo Building"
 "Apostolic Church"
 "Appliances"
 "Appraiser"
 "Arcade"
 "Archaeological Services"
 "Archery"
 "Architect"
 "Argentine Restaurant"
 "Armed Forces"
 "Armored Cars"
 "Aromatherapy"
 "Art Gallery"
 "Art Museum"
 "Art Restoration"
 "Art School"
 "Artistic Services"
 "Arts & Crafts Supply Store"
 "Arts & Entertainment"
 "Arts & Marketing"
 "Asian Fusion Restaurant"
 "Asian Restaurant"
 "Assembly of God"
 "Athletic Education"
 "ATVs & Golf Carts"
 "Auction House"
 "Audiologist"
 "Audiovisual Equipment"
 "Auditorium"
 "Auto Body Shop"
 "Auto Glass"
 "Automation Services"
 "Automobile Leasing"
 "Automotive Consultant"
 "Automotive Customizing"
 "Automotive Manufacturing"
 "Automotive Parts & Accessories"
 "Automotive Repair"
 "Automotive Restoration"
 "Automotive Storage"
 "Automotive Trailer Services"
 "Automotive Wholesaler"
 "Automotive"
 "Aviation Fuel"
 "Aviation School"
 "Awnings & Canopies"
 "Babysitter"
 "Bail Bonds"
 "Bakery"
 "Bands & Musicians"
 "Bank Equipment & Service"
 "Bank"
 "Bankruptcy Lawyer"
 "Baptist Church"
 "Bar & Grill"
 "Bar"
 "Barbecue Restaurant"
 "Barber Shop"
 "Bartending Service"
 "Basque Restaurant"
 "Batting Cage"
 "Beach Resort"
 "Beach"
 "Beauty Salon"
 "Bed and Breakfast"
 "Beer Garden"
 "Belgian Restaurant"
 "Big Box Retailer"
 "Bike Rental & Bike Share"
 "Bike Shop"
 "Bingo Hall"
 "Biotechnology"
 "Blinds & Curtains"
 "Blood Bank"
 "Boat Dealer"
 "Boat Rental"
 "Boat Service"
 "Boating"
 "Book & Magazine Distribution"
 "Book Store"
 "Borough"
 "Bowling Alley"
 "Brazilian Restaurant"
 "Breakfast & Brunch Restaurant"
 "Brewery"
 "Bridal Shop"
 "Bridge"
 "British Restaurant"
 "Broadcasting & Media Production"
 "Brokers & Franchising"
 "Buddhist Temple"
 "Buffet Restaurant"
 "Burger Restaurant"
 "Burial & Cremation Service"
 "Burmese Restaurant"
 "Bus Line"
 "Bus Station"
 "Business Center"
 "Business Consultant"
 "Business Services"
 "Business Supply Service"
 "Butcher"
 "Cabin"
 "Cabinets & Countertops"
 "Cable & Satellite Service"
 "Cafe"
 "Cafeteria"
 "Cajun & Creole Restaurant"
 "Cambodian Restaurant"
 "Camera Store"
 "Camp"
 "Campground"
 "Campus Building"
 "Canadian Restaurant"
 "Candy Store"
 "Cantonese Restaurant"
 "Car Dealership"
 "Car Parts & Accessories"
 "Car Rental"
 "Car Wash & Detailing"
 "Cargo & Freight"
 "Caribbean Restaurant"
 "Carnival Supplies"
 "Carpenter"
 "Carpet & Flooring Store"
 "Carpet Cleaner"
 "Cash Advance Service"
 "Casino"
 "Caterer"
 "Catholic Church"
 "Cemetery"
 "Charismatic Church"
 "Charity Organization"
 "Charter Buses"
 "Cheerleading"
 "Chemicals & Gasses"
 "Chicken Restaurant"
 "Chicken Wings"
 "Child Care"
 "Child Protective Services"
 "Children's Clothing Store"
 "Chinese Restaurant"
 "Chiropractor"
 "Christian Church"
 "Christian Science Church"
 "Church of Christ"
 "Church of God"
 "Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints"
 "Church"
 "Circus"
 "City Hall"
 "City"
 "Classes"
 "Cleaning Service"
 "Clergy"
 "Clinic"
 "Clothing Store"
 "Clothing Supply & Distribution"
 "Clubhouse"
 "Coffee Shop"
 "Collectibles Store"
 "Collection Agency"
 "College & University"
 "Comedy Club"
 "Comic Book Store"
 "Commercial & Industrial Equipment"
 "Commercial & Industrial"
 "Commercial Automotive"
 "Commercial Bank"
 "Commercial Real Estate"
 "Community & Government"
 "Community Center"
 "Community Organization"
 "Computer Services"
 "Computer Store"
 "Computer Training"
 "Computers & Electronics"
 "Concert Venue"
 "Concrete Contractor"
 "Congregational Church"
 "Construction Service & Supply"
 "Consulate & Embassy"
 "Continental Restaurant"
 "Contractor"
 "Convenience Store"
 "Convent & Monastery"
 "Convention Center"
 "Cooking Lesson"
 "Copying & Printing"
 "Copyright Lawyer"
 "Copywriting Service"
 "Corporate Lawyer"
 "Corporate Office"
 "Cosmetics & Beauty Supply"
 "Costume Shop"
 "Cottage"
 "Counseling & Mental Health"
 "Country"
 "County"
 "Courthouse"
 "Credit Counseling"
 "Crêperie"
 "Criminal Lawyer"
 "Crisis Prevention Center"
 "Cruise Excursions"
 "Cruise"
 "Cuban Restaurant"
 "Culinary School"
 "Cultural Gifts Store"
 "Cupcake Shop"
 "Currency Exchange"
 "Cyber Cafe"
 "Damage Restoration Service"
 "Dance Club"
 "Dance Instruction"
 "Dating Service"
 "Day Care & Preschool"
 "Day Spa"
 "Deck & Patio"
 "Deli"
 "Dental Equipment"
 "Dentist"
 "Department Store"
 "Dermatologist"
 "Dessert Restaurant"
 "Dim Sum Restaurant"
 "Diner"
 "Direct Mail Service"
 "Disability Services"
 "Disabled Persons Services"
 "Disaster Relief"
 "Discount Store"
 "Dive Bar"
 "Divorce & Family Lawyer"
 "DJ"
 "DMV"
 "Doctor"
 "Document Service"
 "Dog Training"
 "Dog Walker"
 "Donuts & Bagels"
 "Dorm"
 "Drinking Water Distribution"
 "Drive In Restaurant"
 "Driving Range"
 "Driving School"
 "Drug & Alcohol Rehab"
 "Drugstore"
 "Dry Cleaner"
 "DVD & Video Store"
 "Eastern Orthodox Church"
 "Eco Tours"
 "Education"
 "Educational Camp"
 "Educational Consultant"
 "Educational Organization"
 "Educational Research"
 "Educational Service"
 "Educational Supplies"
 "Electrician"
 "Electronic Equipment Service"
 "Electronics Store"
 "Elementary School"
 "Elevator Services"
 "Email Marketing"
 "Emergency Roadside Service"
 "Emissions Inspection"
 "Employment Agency"
 "Employment Lawyer"
 "Engineering Service"
 "Entertainer"
 "Entertainment Service"
 "Environmental Conservation"
 "Environmental Consultant"
 "Episcopal Church"
 "Equipment Service & Supply"
 "Escrow Services"
 "Estate Lawyer"
 "Estate Planning"
 "Esthethics"
 "Ethiopian Restaurant"
 "Ethnic Grocery Store"
 "Evangelical Church"
 "Event Planner"
 "Event Planning"
 "Event Venue"
 "Event"
 "Excavation & Wrecking"
 "Exchange Program"
 "Exotic Car Rental"
 "Eyewear"
 "Fairground"
 "Family Doctor"
 "Family Medicine Practice"
 "Family Style Restaurant"
 "Farm"
 "Farmers Market"
 "Fashion Designer"
 "Fast Food Restaurant"
 "Ferry & Boat"
 "Filipino Restaurant"
 "Financial Aid"
 "Financial Planning"
 "Financial Services"
 "Fine Dining Restaurant"
 "Fire Protection"
 "Fire Station"
 "Fireplaces"
 "Fireproofing"
 "Fireworks Retailer"
 "First Aid Class"
 "First Aid Service"
 "Fish & Chips Shop"
 "Fishing"
 "Fitness Center"
 "Flea Market"
 "Florist"
 "Fondue Restaurant"
 "Food & Beverage Service & Distribution"
 "Food & Grocery"
 "Food & Restaurant"
 "Food Consultant"
 "Food Stand"
 "Food Truck"
 "Forestry & Logging"
 "Formal Wear"
 "Franchising Service"
 "French Restaurant"
 "Frozen Yogurt Shop"
 "Fruit & Vegetable Store"
 "Full Gospel Church"
 "Funeral Service"
 "Furniture Repair"
 "Furniture Store"
 "Garage Door Services"
 "Garden Center"
 "Gardener"
 "Gas & Chemical Service"
 "Gas Station"
 "Gastropub"
 "Gay Bar"
 "Genealogist"
 "Geologic Service"
 "German Restaurant"
 "Gift Shop"
 "Glass Products"
 "Glass Service"
 "Gluten-Free Restaurant"
 "Go Karting"
 "Golf Course"
 "Government Organization"
 "Governmental Law"
 "Graphic Design"
 "Greek Restaurant"
 "Grocery Store"
 "Gun Range"
 "Gun Store"
 "Gym"
 "Hair & Beauty Supply"
 "Hair Removal"
 "Hair Replacement"
 "Hair Salon"
 "Hairpieces & Extensions"
 "Halal Restaurant"
 "Halfway House"
 "Handwriting Service"
 "Hardware & Tools Service"
 "Hardware Store"
 "Hawaiian Restaurant"
 "Health Agency"
 "Health Care Administration"
 "Health Food Restaurant"
 "Health Food Store"
 "Health Spa"
 "Healthcare Administrator"
 "Heating, Ventilating & Air Conditioning"
 "High School"
 "Highway"
 "Himalayan Restaurant"
 "Hindu Temple"
 "Historical Place"
 "History Museum"
 "Holiness Church"
 "Home Cleaning"
 "Home Decor"
 "Home Improvement"
 "Home Inspection"
 "Home Security"
 "Home Theater Store"
 "Home Window Service"
 "Home"
 "Hookah Lounge"
 "Horse-Drawn Vehicles"
 "Horses"
 "Hospital"
 "Hospitality Service"
 "Hostel"
 "Hot Air Balloons"
 "Hot Dog Joint"
 "Hot Dog Stand"
 "Hotel Supply Service"
 "Hotel"
 "House Sitter"
 "Housewares"
 "Housing & Homeless Shelter"
 "Housing Assistance Service"
 "Hungarian Restaurant"
 "Hunting and Fishing"
 "Ice Cream Parlor"
 "Ice Machines"
 "Ice Skating"
 "Image Consultant"
 "Independent Church"
 "Indian Restaurant"
 "Indonesian Restaurant"
 "Inn"
 "Insurance Agent"
 "Insurance Broker"
 "Interdenominational Church"
 "Interior Designer"
 "Internal Medicine"
 "International Restaurant"
 "Internet Cafe"
 "Internet Service Provider"
 "Inventory Control Service"
 "Investing Service"
 "Irish Restaurant"
 "Island"
 "Italian Restaurant"
 "Janitorial Service"
 "Japanese Restaurant"
 "Jazz Club"
 "Jewelry Store"
 "Jewelry Supplier"
 "Junior High School"
 "Just For Fun"
 "Juvenile Law"
 "Karaoke"
 "Kennel"
 "Kingdom Hall"
 "Kitchen Construction"
 "Kitchen Supplies"
 "Korean Restaurant"
 "Kosher Restaurant"
 "Labor & Employment Law"
 "Laboratory Equipment"
 "Lake"
 "Landmark"
 "Landscaping"
 "Language School"
 "Laser Hair Removal"
 "Laser Tag"
 "Late Night Restaurant"
 "Latin American Restaurant"
 "Laundromat"
 "Law Enforcement"
 "Law Practice"
 "Lebanese Restaurant"
 "Library"
 "Lifestyle Services"
 "Lighting Fixtures"
 "Limo Service"
 "Liquor Store"
 "Live & Raw Food Restaurant"
 "Loans"
 "Lobbyist"
 "Local Education"
 "Locksmith"
 "Lodge"
 "Lodging"
 "Lottery Retailer"
 "Lounge"
 "Luggage Service"
 "Lutheran Church"
 "Maid & Butler"
 "Makeup Artist"
 "Malaysian Restaurant"
 "Malpractice Law"
 "Management Service"
 "Manufacturing"
 "Marina"
 "Marine Equipment"
 "Marine Service Station"
 "Market Research Consultant"
 "Market"
 "Marketing Consultant"
 "Martial Arts"
 "Masonry"
 "Massage"
 "Mattress Manufacturing"
 "Mattress Wholesale"
 "Mattresses & Bedding"
 "Meat Shop"
 "Medical & Health"
 "Medical Center"
 "Medical Equipment"
 "Medical Lab"
 "Medical Research"
 "Medical School"
 "Medical Spa"
 "Medical Supplies"
 "Mediterranean Restaurant"
 "Meeting Room"
 "Mennonite Church"
 "Men's Clothing Store"
 "Merchandising Service"
 "Metals"
 "Methodist Church"
 "Mexican Restaurant"
 "Middle Eastern Restaurant"
 "Middle School"
 "Military Base"
 "Miniature Golf"
 "Mission"
 "Mobile Homes"
 "Mobile Phone Shop"
 "Modeling Agency"
 "Modern Art Museum"
 "Modern European Restaurant"
 "Mongolian Restaurant"
 "Monument"
 "Moroccan Restaurant"
 "Mortgage Brokers"
 "Mosque"
 "Motel"
 "Motorcycle Repair"
 "Motorcycles"
 "Mountain Biking"
 "Mountain"
 "Mover"
 "Movie & Television Studio"
 "Movie Theatre"
 "Museum"
 "Music Lessons & Instruction"
 "Music Production"
 "Music Store"
 "Musical Instrument Store"
 "Nail Salon"
 "Nanny"
 "National Park"
 "Nazarene Church"
 "Neighborhood"
 "Nepalese Restaurant"
 "New American Restaurant"
 "Newspaper"
 "Night Club"
 "Nightlife"
 "Nondenominational Church"
 "Notary Public"
 "Nursing Home"
 "Nursing"
 "Nutritionist"
 "OBGYN"
 "Occupational Safety"
 "Occupational Therapist"
 "Ocean"
 "Office Supplies"
 "Oil Lube & Filter Service"
 "Oncologist"
 "Ophthalmologist"
 "Optometrist"
 "Orchestra"
 "Organization"
 "Other"
 "Otolaryngologist"
 "Outdoor Equipment Store"
 "Outdoor Recreation"
 "Outdoor Services"
 "Outdoors"
 "Outlet Store"
 "Packaging Supplies & Equipment"
 "Paintball"
 "Painter"
 "Pakistani Restaurant"
 "Park"
 "Parking"
 "Party Center"
 "Party Supplies"
 "Passport & Visa Service"
 "Patent Trademark & Copyright Law"
 "Patrol & Security"
 "Paving & Asphalt Service"
 "Pawn Shop"
 "Pediatrics"
 "Pentecostal Church"
 "Performance Venue"
 "Performing Arts Education"
 "Persian Restaurant"
 "Personal Coaching"
 "Personal Trainer"
 "Peruvian Restaurant"
 "Pest Control"
 "Pet Breeder"
 "Pet Cemetery"
 "Pet Groomer"
 "Pet Service"
 "Pet Sitter"
 "Pet Store"
 "Petroleum Services"
 "Petting Zoo"
 "Pharmacy"
 "Pho Restaurant"
 "Photographer"
 "Photographic Services & Equipment"
 "Physical Fitness"
 "Physical Therapist"
 "Physician Assistant"
 "Picnic Ground"
 "Pizza Place"
 "Plastic Surgery"
 "Plastics"
 "Playground"
 "Plumber"
 "Podiatrist"
 "Police Station"
 "Polish Restaurant"
 "Political Organization"
 "Polynesian Restaurant"
 "Pool & Billiards"
 "Port"
 "Portable Building Service"
 "Portable Toilet Rentals"
 "Portuguese Restaurant"
 "Post Office"
 "Pregnancy & Childbirth Service"
 "Presbyterian Church"
 "Preschool"
 "Printing Service"
 "Prison & Correctional Facility"
 "Private Investigator"
 "Private Plane Charter"
 "Private School"
 "Private Transportation"
 "Professional Services"
 "Promotional Item Services"
 "Property Law"
 "Property Management"
 "Psychic"
 "Psychologist"
 "Pub"
 "Public Places & Attractions"
 "Public Relations"
 "Public School"
 "Public Services"
 "Public Square"
 "Public Transportation"
 "Public Utility"
 "Publisher"
 "Race Cars"
 "Race Track"
 "Racquetball Court"
 "Radio & Communication Equipment"
 "Rafting"
 "Railroad"
 "Ramen Restaurant"
 "Real Estate Agent"
 "Real Estate Appraiser"
 "Real Estate Developer"
 "Real Estate Investment"
 "Real Estate Lawyer"
 "Real Estate Service"
 "Real Estate Title & Development"
 "Real Estate"
 "Recreation Center"
 "Recreational Vehicle Dealer"
 "Recruiter"
 "Recycling & Waste Management"
 "Refrigeration Sales & Service"
 "Refrigeration"
 "Region"
 "Religious Book Store"
 "Religious Center"
 "Religious Organization"
 "Religious School"
 "Rent to Own Store"
 "Rental Company"
 "Rental Shop"
 "Repair Service"
 "Reproductive Services"
 "Research Service"
 "Reservoir"
 "Residence & Other"
 "Resort"
 "Restaurant Supply"
 "Restaurant Wholesale"
 "Restaurant"
 "Retirement & Assisted Living Facility"
 "River"
 "Robotics"
 "Rock Climbing"
 "Rodeo"
 "Roller Coaster"
 "Roofer"
 "Rubber Service & Supply"
 "Russian Restaurant"
 "RV Dealership"
 "RV Park"
 "RV Repair"
 "Safety & First Aid Service"
 "Salad Bar"
 "Salvation Army"
 "Sandwich Shop"
 "Scandinavian Restaurant"
 "School Fundraiser"
 "School Transportation"
 "School"
 "Scooter Rental"
 "Screen Printing & Embroidery"
 "Scuba Diving"
 "Seafood Restaurant"
 "Seasonal Store"
 "Secretarial Service"
 "Security"
 "Senior Center"
 "Septic Tank Service"
 "Service Station Supply"
 "Seventh Day Adventist Church"
 "Sewer Service"
 "Sewing & Seamstress"
 "Shoe Store"
 "Shopping & Retail"
 "Shopping District"
 "Shopping Mall"
 "Shopping Service"
 "Signs & Banner Service"
 "Sikh Temple"
 "Singaporean Restaurant"
 "Ski & Snowboard School"
 "Ski Resort"
 "Skin Care"
 "Sky Diving"
 "Smog Check Station"
 "Smoothie & Juice Bar"
 "Snowmobiles"
 "Social Club"
 "Social Services"
 "Solar Energy Service"
 "Sorority & Fraternity"
 "Soul Food Restaurant"
 "Soup Restaurant"
 "Southern Restaurant"
 "Southwestern Restaurant"
 "Spa"
 "Spa, Beauty & Personal Care"
 "Spanish Restaurant"
 "Specialty Grocery Store"
 "Specialty School"
 "Speech Pathologist"
 "Sporting Goods Store"
 "Sports & Recreation"
 "Sports Bar"
 "Sports Center"
 "Sports Club"
 "Sports Instruction"
 "Sports Promoter"
 "Sports Venue & Stadium"
 "Sportswear"
 "Startup"
 "State Park"
 "State"
 "Statue & Fountain"
 "Steakhouse"
 "Storage Service"
 "Storage"
 "Street"
 "Subway & Light Rail Station"
 "Supply & Distribution Services"
 "Surfing Spot"
 "Surveyor"
 "Sushi Restaurant"
 "Swimming Pool Maintenance"
 "Swimming Pool"
 "Swimwear"
 "Symphony"
 "Synagogue"
 "Taiwanese Restaurant"
 "Take Out Restaurant"
 "Tanning Salon Supplier"
 "Tanning Salon"
 "Tapas Bar & Restaurant"
 "Tattoo & Piercing"
 "Tax Preparation"
 "Taxi"
 "Taxidermist"
 "Tea Room"
 "Technical Institute"
 "Teeth Whitening"
 "Telemarketing Service"
 "Tennis"
 "Tex-Mex Restaurant"
 "Textiles"
 "Thai Restaurant"
 "Theatre"
 "Theatrical Equipment"
 "Theme Park"
 "Thrift or Consignment Store"
 "Ticket Sales"
 "Tire Dealer"
 "Tobacco Store"
 "Tools Service"
 "Tour Company"
 "Tour Guide"
 "Tourist Attraction"
 "Tourist Information"
 "Tours & Sightseeing"
 "Towing Service"
 "Toy Store"
 "Trade School"
 "Traffic School"
 "Trailer  Rental"
 "Train Station"
 "Translator"
 "Transportation Service"
 "Travel & Transportation"
 "Travel Agency"
 "Trophies & Engraving"
 "Truck Rental"
 "Truck Towing"
 "Turkish Restaurant"
 "Tutoring"
 "Upholstery Service"
 "Urban Farm"
 "Vacation Home Rental"
 "Vegetarian & Vegan Restaurant"
 "Vending Machine Service"
 "Veterinarian"
 "Video Games"
 "Vietnamese Restaurant"
 "Vintage Store"
 "Wallpaper"
 "Warehouse"
 "Waste Management"
 "Water Filtration & Treatment"
 "Water Park"
 "Web Design"
 "Web Development"
 "Wedding Planning"
 "Well Water Drilling Service"
 "Wholesale & Supply Store"
 "Wig Store"
 "Wildlife Sanctuary"
 "Wills & Estate Lawyer"
 "Window Service & Repair"
 "Wine Bar"
 "Winery & Vineyard"
 "Women's Clothing Store"
 "Women's Health"
 "Workplace & Office"
 "Writing Service"
 "Yoga & Pilates"
 "Youth Organization"
 "Zoo & Aquarium"
```

Comment: You can use the graph api explorer to fetch the most up-to-date list easily with this link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dplacetopic%26topic_filter%3Dall%26limit%3D5000&version=v2.5

Comment: This is a great answer, but unfortunately it only works for `place`s. Would be good to have the same query for `page`s as well.

Answer (score 4):

this should be the complete list, reverse engineered as mentioned above:

```
2506,Airport
2508,Arts/Entertainment/Nightlife
2523,Attractions/Things to Do
2509,Automotive
2512,Bank/Financial Services
2100,Bar
1305,Book Store
2518,Business Services
2264,Church/Religious Organization
2101,Club
2519,Community/Government
1209,Concert Venue
2250,Education
2511,Event Planning/Event Services
2513,Food/Grocery
2514,Health/Medical/Pharmacy
2515,Home Improvement
2527,Hospital/Clinic
2501,Hotel
2503,Landmark
1306,Library
2500,Local Business
1111,Movie Theater
2528,Museum/Art Gallery
2231,Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods
2516,Pet Services
2517,Professional Services
2522,Public Places
2520,Real Estate
1900,Restaurant/Cafe
2601,School
2521,Shopping/Retail
2510,Spas/Beauty/Personal Care
2507,Sports Venue
2524,Sports/Recreation/Activities
2525,Tours/Sightseeing
2505,Transit Stop
2526,Transportation
2602,University
2244,Aerospace/Defense
2240,Automobiles and Parts
2234,Bank/Financial Institution
2254,Biotechnology
2606,Cause
2247,Chemicals
2264,Church/Religious Organization
2260,Community Organization
2200,Company
2255,Computers/Technology
2248,Consulting/Business Services
2250,Education
2238,Energy/Utility
2251,Engineering/Construction
2246,Farming/Agriculture
2252,Food/Beverages
2604,Government Organization
2214,Health/Beauty
2243,Health/Medical/Pharmaceuticals
2241,Industrials
2236,Insurance Company
2256,Internet/Software
2249,Legal/Law
2233,Media/News/Publishing
2245,Mining/Materials
2235,Non-Governmental Organization (NGO)
2603,Non-Profit Organization
2600,Organization
2261,Political Organization
2618,Political Party
2239,Retail and Consumer Merchandise
2601,School
2237,Small Business
2253,Telecommunication
2242,Transport/Freight
2258,Travel/Leisure
2602,University
2301,App
2215,Appliances
2232,Baby Goods/Kids Goods
2206,Bags/Luggage
2216,Building Materials
2208,Camera/Photo
2205,Cars
2209,Clothing
2217,Commercial Equipment
2210,Computers
2263,Drugs
2213,Electronics
2252,Food/Beverages
2219,Furniture
2300,Games/Toys
2214,Health/Beauty
2218,Home Decor
2220,Household Supplies
2226,Jewelry/Watches
2221,Kitchen/Cooking
2227,Movies/Music
1204,Musical Instrument
2212,Office Supplies
2231,Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods
2222,Patio/Garden
2230,Pet Supplies
2201,Product/Service
2211,Software
2223,Tools/Equipment
2262,Vitamins/Supplements
2202,Website
2224,Wine/Spirits
1103,Actor/Director
1601,Artist
1600,Athlete
1301,Author
1609,Business Person
1606,Chef
1802,Coach
1610,Comedian
1614,Dancer
1608,Doctor
1308,Editor
1611,Entertainer
1113,Fictional Character
1701,Government Official
1604,Journalist
1607,Lawyer
1612,Monarch
1202,Musician/Band
1605,News Personality
1700,Politician
1108,Producer
1602,Public Figure
1613,Teacher
1109,Writer
1200,Album
1803,Amateur Sports Team
1300,Book
1305,Book Store
1208,Concert Tour
1209,Concert Venue
1113,Fictional Character
1306,Library
1307,Magazine
1105,Movie
1111,Movie Theater
1212,Music Award
1213,Music Chart
1207,Music Video
1204,Musical Instrument
1206,Playlist
1801,Professional Sports Team
1210,Radio Station
1211,Record Label
1804,School Sports Team
1201,Song
1800,Sports League
2507,Sports Venue
1110,Studio
1404,TV Channel
1402,TV Network
1400,TV Show
1112,TV/Movie Award
```

Answer (score 4):

150 categories as of June 3rd, 2014, API v2.0. You should note that these are only the main categories of a page. Each [Facebook Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page) has a `category_list` array field that has subcategories that are not shown here. You can get a list of all subcategories for places via the graph API by this query: [`search?type=place_topic&topic_filter=all`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search?type=place_topic&topic_filter=all&version=v2.0)

FYI since Facebook changes all the time, the easiest way to obtain the list is to do as @RichSutton suggested and go to the [Create Page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php) page, and do inspect element on the drop-down lists. 5-6 copy-pastes, a regex later you have your complete list (with some duplicates).

```
1103, Actor/Director
1105, Movie
1108, Producer
1109, Writer
1110, Studio
1111, Movie Theater
1112, TV/Movie Award
1113, Fictional Character
1114, Movie Character
1200, Album
1201, Song
1202, Musician/Band
1207, Music Video
1208, Concert Tour
1209, Concert Venue
1210, Radio Station
1211, Record Label
1212, Music Award
1213, Music Chart
1300, Book
1301, Author
1305, Book Store
1306, Library
1307, Magazine
1309, Book Series
1400, TV Show
1402, TV Network
1404, TV Channel
1600, Athlete
1601, Artist
1602, Public Figure
1604, Journalist
1605, News Personality
1606, Chef
1607, Lawyer
1608, Doctor
1609, Business Person
1610, Comedian
1611, Entertainer
1613, Teacher
1614, Dancer
1615, Designer
1616, Photographer
1617, Entrepreneur
1700, Politician
1701, Government Official
1800, Sports League
1801, Professional Sports Team
1802, Coach
1803, Amateur Sports Team
1804, School Sports Team
1900, Restaurant/Cafe
2100, Bar
2101, Club
2200, Company
2201, Product/Service
2202, Website
2205, Cars
2206, Bags/Luggage
2208, Camera/Photo
2209, Clothing
2210, Computers
2211, Software
2212, Office Supplies
2213, Electronics
2214, Health/Beauty
2215, Appliances
2216, Building Materials
2217, Commercial Equipment
2218, Home Decor
2219, Furniture
2220, Household Supplies
2221, Kitchen/Cooking
2222, Patio/Garden
2223, Tools/Equipment
2224, Wine/Spirits
2226, Jewelry/Watches
2230, Pet Supplies
2231, Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods
2232, Baby Goods/Kids Goods
2233, Media/News/Publishing
2234, Bank/Financial Institution
2235, Non-Governmental Organization (NGO)
2236, Insurance Company
2237, Small Business
2238, Energy/Utility
2239, Retail and Consumer Merchandise
2240, Automobiles and Parts
2241, Industrials
2242, Transport/Freight
2243, Health/Medical/Pharmaceuticals
2244, Aerospace/Defense
2245, Mining/Materials
2246, Farming/Agriculture
2247, Chemicals
2248, Consulting/Business Services
2249, Legal/Law
2250, Education
2251, Engineering/Construction
2252, Food/Beverages
2253, Telecommunication
2254, Biotechnology
2255, Computers/Technology
2256, Internet/Software
2258, Travel/Leisure
2260, Community Organization
2261, Political Organization
2262, Vitamins/Supplements
2263, Drugs
2264, Church/Religious Organization
2265, Phone/Tablet
2300, Games/Toys
2301, App Page
2302, Video Game
2303, Board Game
2500, Local Business
2501, Hotel
2503, Landmark
2506, Airport
2507, Sports Venue
2508, Arts/Entertainment/Nightlife
2509, Automotive
2510, Spas/Beauty/Personal Care
2511, Event Planning/Event Services
2512, Bank/Financial Services
2513, Food/Grocery
2514, Health/Medical/Pharmacy
2515, Home Improvement
2516, Pet Services
2517, Professional Services
2518, Business Services
2519, Community/Government
2520, Real Estate
2521, Shopping/Retail
2522, Public Places
2523, Attractions/Things to Do
2524, Sports/Recreation/Activities
2525, Tours/Sightseeing
2526, Transportation
2527, Hospital/Clinic
2528, Museum/Art Gallery
2600, Organization
2601, School
2602, University
2603, Non-Profit Organization
2604, Government Organization
2606, Cause
2618, Political Party
2632, Pet
2637, Middle School
```

Comment: There's 150 categories in this list, hot 156.

Comment: You're right, the original post I post I put had 6 duplicates, but after removing them I forgot to change the total count. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is always fresh list of category:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dplacetopic%26topic_filter%3Dall%26limit%3D10000&version=v2.6

If you want get full list of category, best way is create openGraph request to this endpoint:
/search?type=placetopic&topic_filter=all&limit=10000

Comment: yes, of course :) I thought that is clear for everyone :)

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes since this is the only way to get an up to date list.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plain (e.g. no jQuery required) Javascript function that will extract the id/category pairs from the create-a-page page:

```
function get_categories() {
    var result = {};
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var obj = options[i];
        if (obj.parentNode.id == 'category' && obj.value != '0')
            result[obj.value] = obj.innerHTML;
    };
    return result;
}
```

Comment: But note: there's no real reason to believe that this list is complete at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

The authoritative list can be reverse engineered from here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php.  But there currently is no way to get this programatically from the graph API.  +1 for adding it.

Comment: Use something like: `Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('select option'), function(c){ return c.textContent  }).sort();`

Answer (score 1):

Sorted & Merged all the lists and from the create page :

151 entries :

```
Actor/Director
Aerospace/Defence
Airport
Album
Amateur Sports Team
Appliances
App Page
Artist
Arts/Entertainment/Nightlife
Author
Baby Goods/Kids Goods
Bags/Luggage
Bank/Financial Institution
Bank/Financial Services
Biotechnology
Blogger
Board Game
Book
Book Series
Bookshop
Building Materials
Business Person
Business Services
Camera/Photo
Cars
Cars and Parts
Cause
Chef
Chemicals
Church/Religious Organisation
Cinema
Clothing
Club
Coach
Comedian
Commercial Equipment
Community/Government
Community Organisation
Company</option>
Computers
Computers/Technology
Concert Tour
Concert Venue
Consulting/Business Services
Dancer
Designer
DIY
Doctor
Education
Electronics
Energy/Utility
Engineering/Construction
Entertainer
Entrepreneur
Event Planning/Event Services
Farming/Agriculture
Fictional Character
Film
Film Character
Food/Drink
Food/Groceries
Furniture
Games/Toys
Government Official
Government Organisation
Health/Beauty
Health/Medical/Pharmaceuticals
Health/Medical/Pharmacy
Home Decor
Hospital/Clinic
Hotel
Household Supplies
Industrials
Insurance Company
Internet/Software
Jewellery/Watches
Journalist
Kitchen/Cooking
Landmark
Lawyer
Legal/Law
Library
Local Business
Magazine
Media/News/Publishing
Medications
Middle School
Mining/Materials
Museum/Art Gallery
Music Award
Music Chart
Musician/Band
Music Video
News Personality
Non-governmental Organisation (NGO)
Non-profit Organisation
Nursery
Office Supplies
Organisation
Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods
Patio/Garden
Performance Art
Pet
Pet Services
Pet Supplies
Phone/Tablet
Photographer
Political Organisation
Political Party
Politician
Primary School
Producer
Product/Service
Professional Services
Property
Public Figure
Public Places
Radio Station
Record Label
Restaurant/Café
Retail and Consumer Merchandise
School
School Sports Team
Shopping/Retail
Small Business
Software
Song
Spas/Beauty/Personal Care
Sports League
Sportsperson
Sports/Recreation/Activities
Sports Team
Sports Venue
Studio
Teacher
Telecommunication
Tools/Equipment
Tours/Sightseeing
Transport
Transport/Freight
Travel/Leisure
TV Channel
TV/Film Award
TV Network
TV Programme
University
Video Game
Vitamins/Supplements
Website
Wine/Spirits
Writer
```

Updated on 05-06-2015

Answer (score 1):

Category List as of Oct 17th 2013. Took all the categories and cat ID's from page settings.

```
{
"1301":"Author",
"1300":"Book",
"1309":"Book Series",
"1305":"Book Store",
"1306":"Library",
"1308":"Literary Editor",
"1307":"Magazine",
"1304":"Publisher",
"2301":"App Page",
"2215":"Appliances",
"2232":"Baby Goods/Kids Goods",
"2206":"Bags/Luggage",
"2303":"Board Game",
"2216":"Building Materials",
"2208":"Camera/Photo",
"2205":"Cars",
"2209":"Clothing",
"2217":"Commercial Equipment",
"2210":"Computers",
"2263":"Drugs",
"2213":"Electronics",
"2252":"Food/Beverages",
"2219":"Furniture",
"2300":"Games/Toys",
"2214":"Health/Beauty",
"2218":"Home Decor",
"2220":"Household Supplies",
"2226":"Jewelry/Watches",
"2221":"Kitchen/Cooking",
"2212":"Office Supplies",
"2231":"Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods",
"2222":"Patio/Garden",
"2230":"Pet Supplies",
"2265":"Phone/Tablet",
"2201":"Product/Service",
"2211":"Software",
"2223":"Tools/Equipment",
"2302":"Video Game",
"2262":"Vitamins/Supplements",
"2202":"Website",
"2224":"Wine/Spirits",
"2244":"Aerospace/Defense",
"2240":"Automobiles and Parts",
"2234":"Bank/Financial Institution",
"2254":"Biotechnology",
"2606":"Cause",
"2247":"Chemicals",
"2264":"Church/Religious Organization",
"2260":"Community Organization",
"2200":"Company",
"2255":"Computers/Technology",
"2248":"Consulting/Business Services",
"2250":"Education",
"2238":"Energy/Utility",
"2251":"Engineering/Construction",
"2246":"Farming/Agriculture",
"2252":"Food/Beverages",
"2604":"Government Organization",
"2214":"Health/Beauty",
"2243":"Health/Medical/Pharmaceuticals",
"2241":"Industrials",
"2236":"Insurance Company",
"2256":"Internet/Software",
"2249":"Legal/Law",
"2233":"Media/News/Publishing",
"2245":"Mining/Materials",
"2235":"Non-Governmental Organization (NGO)",
"2603":"Non-Profit Organization",
"2600":"Organization",
"2261":"Political Organization",
"2618":"Political Party",
"2239":"Retail and Consumer Merchandise",
"2601":"School",
"2237":"Small Business",
"2253":"Telecommunication",
"2242":"Transport/Freight",
"2258":"Travel/Leisure",
"2602":"University",
"2506":"Airport",
"2508":"Arts/Entertainment/Nightlife",
"2523":"Attractions/Things to Do",
"2509":"Automotive",
"2512":"Bank/Financial Services",
"2100":"Bar",
"1305":"Book Store",
"2518":"Business Services",
"2264":"Church/Religious Organization",
"2101":"Club",
"2519":"Community/Government",
"1209":"Concert Venue",
"1608":"Doctor",
"2250":"Education",
"2511":"Event Planning/Event Services",
"2513":"Food/Grocery",
"2514":"Health/Medical/Pharmacy",
"2515":"Home Improvement",
"2527":"Hospital/Clinic",
"2501":"Hotel",
"2503":"Landmark",
"1607":"Lawyer",
"1306":"Library",
"2500":"Local Business",
"1111":"Movie Theater",
"2528":"Museum/Art Gallery",
"2231":"Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods",
"2516":"Pet Services",
"2517":"Professional Services",
"2522":"Public Places",
"2520":"Real Estate",
"1900":"Restaurant/Cafe",
"2601":"School",
"2521":"Shopping/Retail",
"2510":"Spas/Beauty/Personal Care",
"2507":"Sports Venue",
"2524":"Sports/Recreation/Activities",
"2525":"Tours/Sightseeing",
"2526":"Transportation",
"2602":"University",
"1103":"Actor/Director",
"1113":"Fictional Character",
"1105":"Movie",
"1114":"Movie Character",
"1111":"Movie Theater",
"1108":"Producer",
"1110":"Studio",
"1112":"TV/Movie Award",
"1109":"Writer",
"1200":"Album",
"1208":"Concert Tour",
"1209":"Concert Venue",
"1212":"Music Award",
"1213":"Music Chart",
"1207":"Music Video",
"1202":"Musician/Band",
"1210":"Radio Station",
"1211":"Record Label",
"1201":"Song",
"2612":"Community",
"2631":"Just For Fun",
"1103":"Actor/Director",
"1601":"Artist",
"1600":"Athlete",
"1301":"Author",
"1609":"Business Person",
"1606":"Chef",
"1802":"Coach",
"1610":"Comedian",
"1614":"Dancer",
"1611":"Entertainer",
"1113":"Fictional Character",
"1701":"Government Official",
"1604":"Journalist",
"1612":"Monarch",
"1114":"Movie Character",
"1202":"Musician/Band",
"1605":"News Personality",
"2632":"Pet",
"1700":"Politician",
"1108":"Producer",
"1602":"Public Figure",
"1613":"Teacher",
"1109":"Writer",
"1803":"Amateur Sports Team",
"1600":"Athlete",
"1802":"Coach",
"1801":"Professional Sports Team",
"1804":"School Sports Team",
"1805":"Sports Event",
"1800":"Sports League",
"2507":"Sports Venue",
"1103":"Actor/Director",
"1405":"Episode",
"1113":"Fictional Character",
"1114":"Movie Character",
"1110":"Studio",
"1404":"TV Channel",
"1402":"TV Network",
"1400":"TV Show",
"1112":"TV/Movie Award",
"1109":"Writer",
"2701":"Arts/Humanities Website",
"2702":"Business/Economy Website",
"2703":"Computers/Internet Website",
"2704":"Education Website",
"2705":"Entertainment Website",
"2706":"Government Website",
"2707":"Health/Wellness Website",
"2708":"Home/Garden Website",
"2715":"Local/Travel Website",
"2709":"News/Media Website",
"2700":"Personal Blog",
"2717":"Personal Website",
"2710":"Recreation/Sports Website",
"2711":"Reference Website",
"2712":"Regional Website",
"2713":"Science Website",
"2714":"Society/Culture Website",
"2716":"Teens/Kids Website"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ross, although I am not 100% sure about this, my guess would be that this data is kept and updated internally by Facebook, and so if you wanted to use it in an app, you would have to make an array of some kind yourself containing all of the (current) categories used by Facebook - as you have outlined here (I have looked extensively through their API, Graph, etc documentation, and do not recall seeing any mention of how you can get categories for interests).

You might also have a look at this link:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

Best.

Answer (score 0):

I had to extract all categories and place topics, but I found problems extracting them using the solutions provided in this thread. The query of @not_this_again does in his [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018091/5189200) does not return a complete list of place topics, I don't know why.

I found that Facebook returns categories as well as place topics in the `category_list` attribute of [pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page). Therefore, I extracted about 400k places and processed their category list to get as much results as I could. The results were obtained the 20th of October 2017.

I hope it helps, Xavi

204 categories:

```
1103    Actor/Director
1105    Movie
1106    Movie Genre
1108    Producer
1109    Writer
1110    Studio
1111    Movie Theater
1112    TV/Movie Award
1113    Fictional Character
1114    Movie Character
1200    Album
1201    Song
1202    Musician/Band
1203    Musical Genre
1204    Musical Instrument
1205    Music
1207    Music Video
1208    Concert Tour
1209    Concert Venue
1210    Radio Station
1211    Record Label
1212    Music Award
1213    Music Chart
1300    Book
1301    Author
1302    Book Genre
1305    Book Store
1306    Library
1307    Magazine
1308    Literary Editor
1309    Book Series
1400    TV Show
1401    TV Genre
1402    TV Network
1404    TV Channel
1500    Interest
1501    Sport
1600    Athlete
1601    Artist
1602    Public Figure
1604    Journalist
1605    News Personality
1606    Chef
1607    Lawyer
1608    Doctor
1609    Business Person
1610    Comedian
1611    Entertainer
1613    Teacher
1614    Dancer
1615    Designer
1616    Photographer
1617    Entrepreneur
1700    Politician
1701    Government Official
1800    Sports League
1801    Professional Sports Team
1802    Coach
1803    Amateur Sports Team
1804    School Sports Team
1805    Sports Event
1900    Restaurant/Cafe
1901    Cuisine
2000    Food
2100    Bar
2101    Club
2200    Company
2201    Product/Service
2202    Website
2203    Brand/Company Type
2205    Cars
2206    Bags/Luggage
2208    Camera/Photo
2209    Clothing
2210    Computers
2211    Software
2212    Office Supplies
2213    Electronics
2214    Health/Beauty
2215    Appliances
2216    Building Materials
2217    Commercial Equipment
2218    Home Decor
2219    Furniture
2220    Household Supplies
2221    Kitchen/Cooking
2222    Patio/Garden
2223    Tools/Equipment
2224    Wine/Spirits
2226    Jewelry/Watches
2230    Pet Supplies
2231    Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods
2232    Baby Goods/Kids Goods
2233    Media/News/Publishing
2234    Bank/Financial Institution
2235    Non-Governmental Organization (NGO)
2236    Insurance Company
2237    Small Business
2238    Energy/Utility
2239    Retail and Consumer Merchandise
2240    Automobiles and Parts
2241    Industrials
2242    Transport/Freight
2243    Health/Medical/Pharmaceuticals
2244    Aerospace/Defense
2245    Mining/Materials
2246    Farming/Agriculture
2247    Chemicals
2248    Consulting/Business Services
2249    Legal/Law
2250    Education
2251    Engineering/Construction
2252    Food/Beverages
2253    Telecommunication
2254    Biotechnology
2255    Computers/Technology
2256    Internet/Software
2257    Tobacco Company
2258    Travel/Leisure
2260    Community Organization
2261    Political Organization
2262    Vitamins/Supplements
2263    Drugs
2264    Church/Religious Organization
2265    Phone/Tablet
2300    Games/Toys
2301    App Page
2302    Video Game
2303    Board Game
2401    City
2405    Neighborhood
2500    Local Business
2501    Hotel
2503    Landmark
2505    Transit Stop
2506    Airport
2507    Sports Venue
2508    Arts/Entertainment/Nightlife
2509    Automotive
2510    Spas/Beauty/Personal Care
2511    Event Planning/Event Services
2512    Bank/Financial Services
2513    Food/Grocery
2514    Health/Medical/Pharmacy
2515    Home Improvement
2516    Pet Services
2517    Professional Services
2518    Business Services
2519    Community/Government
2520    Real Estate
2521    Shopping/Retail
2522    Public Places
2523    Attractions/Things to Do
2524    Sports/Recreation/Activities
2525    Tours/Sightseeing
2526    Transportation
2527    Hospital/Clinic
2528    Museum/Art Gallery
2600    Organization
2601    School
2602    University
2603    Non-Profit Organization
2604    Government Organization
2606    Cause
2607    Religious Place of Worship
2608    Field of Study
2609    Concentration or Major
2611    Work Position
2612    Community
2613    Degree
2617    Work Project
2618    Political Party
2619    Course
2620    Political Ideology
2621    Animal
2622    Animal Breed
2624    Article
2625    Competition
2629    Junior High School
2632    Pet
2637    Middle School
2700    Personal Blog
2701    Arts & Humanities Website
2702    Business & Economy Website
2703    Computers & Internet Website
2704    Education Website
2705    Entertainment Website
2706    Government Website
2707    Health & Wellness Website
2708    Home & Garden Website
2709    News & Media Website
2710    Recreation & Sports Website
2711    Reference Website
2712    Regional Website
2713    Science Website
2714    Society & Culture Website
2715    Local & Travel Website
2716    Teens & Kids Website
2717    Personal Website
2900    Science
2902    Video
2903    Art
3006    Medical Procedure
3107    Geographical Place
```

and 1201 place topics that are available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/xmellado/d55a29055b958ebb4f9686e3f4d6caf6) (besides categories, too).