# The list of all possible Like categories for Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Pages — Authoritative List of Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216648/facebook-pages-authoritative-list-of-categories)

Where I can find the full list of all possible "like" categories in Facebook Graph API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8576572/220637

Answer (score 0):

the closest I've found is at the [create a page in facebook](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php). It seems that the like category is related to the page category of what is being liked. You could look at the different categories for each page type.