# List of all possible categories?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find out about a Facebook user's interests based on pages they like, etc. Is there any list with all possible categories? Or any chance to get them from the API?

I found this thread; [Facebook Pages — Authoritative List of Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216648/facebook-pages-authoritative-list-of-categories/8576572#8576572)

But its pretty old.

As mentioned in the thread above, i could reverse engineer them from this page:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php

But as the data is there, it would be nice to get it directly from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API that returns this as a definitive, but surely you could just track the unique values you receive when looking at a user's list of pages?

Comment: Yeah, I could map the unique ids to the list recivied from https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php . But it should have been nice with a list of all categories and ids.