# Facebook Page Categories

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to find a master list of categories for Facebook pages that are of type=place. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216648/facebook-pages-authoritative-list-of-categories) gets the authoritative list by scraping the list of categories facebook presents when you try to create a new page. The problem with this is that although this is valid when you access page.category via the Graph API, this is totally wrong when you access page.categories from FQL. I wrote a small python script that pulls a list of places along with their categories this query:

`search?center=40.717209,-74.006335&fields=id&type=place&limit=1000` (Places in Manhattan seemed a good starting point)

and I have the following result (I've had to snip a generous portion of the results to stick to the stackoverflow char limit). Keep in mind that the first category is pulled from GraphAPI.Page.Category while any of the subsequent ones are pulled from FQL.Page.Categories. As you can see below there are many discrepancies. FQL.Page.categories always seems to have a lot more detail than GraphAPI.Page.Category. (Restaurant vs French Restaurant / Burger Joint etc.). If you visit the facebook.com/$pageid, you'd also notice that they prefer FQL.Page.Categories instead of the data from the GraphAPI.

So what's going on here? Is there a masterlist ? Is there some clever hacky way to get a list of categories from FQL?

```
{
   "100383549148":[
      "Restaurant/cafe", --GraphAPI.Page.Category
      "French Restaurant", -- FQL.Page.Categories
      "Fine Dining Restaurant" -- FQL.Page.Categories
   ],
   "138834692818669":[
      "Local business", --GraphAPI.Page.Category
      "Modeling Agency" -- FQL.Page.Categories (and so-on)
   ],
   "151071684933933":[
      "Local business",
      "Department Store",
      "Shopping Mall",
      "Clothing Store"
   ],
   "284861728915":[
      "Retail and consumer merchandise",
      "Clothing Store"
   ],
   "41454242394":[
      "Local business",
      "Electronics Store",
      "Camera Store"
   ],
   "55561367656":[
      "Museum/art gallery",
      "Shopping & Retail",
      "Professional Services"
   ],
   "264714992548":[
      "Club",
      "Night Club"
   ],
   "236943526320075":[
      "Sports/recreation/activities",
      "Pool & Billiards",
      "Sports Bar",
      "Lounge"
   ],
   "58981424089":[
      "Company",
      "Modeling Agency"
   ],
   "120291857982113":[
      "Local business",
      "Bar"
   ],
   "10764587274":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Dance Instruction",
      "Tour Company",
      "Performance Venue"
   ],
   "37982488243":[
      "Museum/art gallery",
      "Museum",
      "Art Gallery"
   ],
   "183682541678235":[
      "Local business",
      "Lodging"
   ],
   "172763729438997":[
      "Public places",
      "Landmark",
      "Historical Place",
      "Tourist Attraction"
   ],
   "211710202241763":[
      "Local business",
      "Mediterranean Restaurant"
   ],
   "415540745185467":[
      "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
      "Gay Bar",
      "Night Club"
   ],
   "121315784548445":[
      "Local business",
      "Italian Restaurant"
   ],
   "300247046737840":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Kosher Restaurant",
      "Lounge",
      "Party Center"
   ],
   "150466084967526":[
      "Publisher",
      "Publisher"
   ],
   "135086246507084":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Religious Center"
   ],
   "135341373539":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Medical & Health",
      "Charity Organization"
   ],
   "81517275796":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Organization"
   ],
   "19064794857":[
      "Professional sports team",
      "Sports Venue/Stadium"
   ],
   "327239417310605":[
      "Museum/art gallery",
      "Museum/Art Gallery"
   ],
   "297399360348054":[
      "Transportation",
      "Taxi",
      "Limo Service",
      "Transportation Service"
   ],
   "175752663777":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "143900978992817":[
      "Local business",
      "Shopping District",
      "Street",
      "Tourist Attraction"
   ],
   "399548274399":[
      "Shopping/retail",
      "Shopping & Retail"
   ],
   "175047719208063":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "119384445132":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "American Restaurant"
   ],
   "22301079793":[
      "Museum/art gallery",
      "Museum"
   ],
   "192081037473294":[
      "Local business",
      "Restaurant",
      "Bakery",
      "Food & Grocery"
   ],
   "109530759101383":[
      "Shopping/retail",
      "Shopping & Retail"
   ],
   "108432842557945":[
      "Shopping/retail",
      "Shopping & Retail"
   ],
   "405121362889168":[
      "Shopping/retail",
      "Jewelry Store"
   ],
   "126735894061992":[
      "Local business",
      "Real Estate Agent",
      "Shopping Mall"
   ],
   "113040605463526":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Bar",
      "Breakfast & Brunch Restaurant"
   ],
   "113471305348354":[
      "Bar",
      "Event Venue",
      "Lounge",
      "Bar"
   ],
   "20807115532":[
      "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
      "Theatre",
      "Concert Venue",
      "Performance Venue"
   ],
   "317722188254508":[
      "Company",
      "Auction House"
   ],
   "6037303508":[
      "Shopping/retail",
      "Children"      s Clothing Store",
      "Furniture Store"
   ],
   "186625831353512":[
      "Local business",
      "Steakhouse"
   ],
   "167155736682339":[
      "Local business",
      "Restaurant",
      "Coffee Shop"
   ],
   "163987300342863":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "26426125254":[
      "Professional sports team",
      "Professional Sports Team"
   ],
   "167722129905749":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "227979715301":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "337639182923404":[
      "Spas/beauty/personal care",
      "Spa, Beauty & Personal Care"
   ],
   "20783785529":[
      "Transport/freight",
      "Transport/Freight"
   ],
   "164567850333782":[
      "Neighborhood",
      "Neighborhood"
   ],
   "307743509286436":[
      "Computers/technology",
      "Computers/Technology"
   ],
   "43983956066":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "199430201205":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "111252343746":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Food & Restaurant"
   ],
   "472847742746995":[
      "Local business",
      "Restaurant"
   ],
   "179497828749951":[
      "Club",
      "Night Club"
   ],
   "161474093878515":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "39528752125":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "198313800215088":[
      "Local business",
      "Hotel"
   ],
   "60444029358":[
      "Bar",
      "Bar",
      "Food & Restaurant"
   ],
   "103486486369895":[
      "Retail and consumer merchandise",
      "Retail and Consumer Merchandise"
   ],
   "140129689372461":[
      "Local business",
      "Restaurant"
   ],
   "143914832316044":[
      "Local business",
      "Wine Bar",
      "Winery/Vineyard",
      "Food & Restaurant"
   ],
   "133898386624065":[
      "Local business",
      "Movie Theatre"
   ],
   "141415742592562":[
      "Local business",
      "Coffee Shop",
      "Shopping & Retail"
   ],
   "140714402637502":[
      "Local business",
      "Clothing Store"
   ],
   "108045259252040":[
      "Local business",
      "Landmark",
      "Tourist Attraction",
      "Street"
   ],
   "352390428187284":[
      "Professional services",
      "Professional Services"
   ],
   "114017981961825":[
      "Local business",
      "Transportation Service",
      "Public Transportation",
      "Airport Terminal"
   ],
   "121080287904911":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Restaurant"
   ],
   "178218403548":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Italian Restaurant"
   ],
   "148374017533":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "173429212678086":[
      "Public places",
      "Shopping & Retail",
      "Tourist Attraction",
      "Business Center"
   ],
   "183143071724041":[
      "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
      "Theatre",
      "Event"
   ],
   "126163559725":[
      "Consulting/business services",
      "Consulting/Business Services"
   ],
   "204100883016192":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "49460183496":[
      "Hotel",
      "Hotel",
      "Arts & Entertainment",
      "Bar"
   ],
   "130599090398237":[
      "Professional services",
      "Photographic Services & Equipment"
   ],
   "116067108421555":[
      "Local business",
      "Chinese Restaurant",
      "Family Style Restaurant"
   ],
   "197062023701792":[
      "Local business",
      "Shopping District",
      "Public Places & Attractions",
      "Neighborhood"
   ],
   "145952055437010":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "97466887664":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "157317837643302":[
      "Real estate",
      "Real Estate"
   ],
   "395554417161429":[
      "Community/government",
      "Community & Government"
   ],
   "159356944133682":[
      "Company",
      "Tea Room",
      "Coffee Shop"
   ],
   "102038963189019":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Mexican Restaurant",
      "Tex-Mex Restaurant"
   ],
   "39875583837":[
      "Attractions/things to do",
      "Landmark",
      "Public Square",
      "Outdoors"
   ],
   "102589285262":[
      "Education",
      "Education",
      "Organization"
   ],
   "86422467669":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Chinese Restaurant"
   ],
   "20957710121":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Park",
      "Community Organization",
      "Public Places & Attractions"
   ],
   "130436540348552":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Italian Restaurant",
      "Pizza Place"
   ],
   "122867824491702":[
      "Bar",
      "Event Venue",
      "Burger Restaurant",
      "Sports Bar"
   ],
   "128560797202056":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "75219157496":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Residence & Other",
      "Medical & Health",
      "Organization"
   ],
   "159959957440081":[
      "Legal/law",
      "Legal/Law"
   ],
   "124764974262852":[
      "Local business",
      "Coffee Shop"
   ],
   "294816017273462":[
      "Company",
      "Food & Restaurant"
   ],
   "189237751159005":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "111576255547949":[
      "Local business",
      "Restaurant",
      "Bar",
      "Karaoke"
   ],
   "283683171653148":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Latin American Restaurant",
      "Mexican Restaurant",
      "Seafood Restaurant"
   ],
   "217073478323499":[
      "Local business",
      "School",
      "Trade School",
      "College/University"
   ],
   "110069639603":[
      "Government organization",
      "Government Organization"
   ],
   "113479128686922":[
      "Local business",
      "Breakfast & Brunch Restaurant",
      "American Restaurant"
   ],
   "138375219537435":[
      "Bar",
      "Gastropub",
      "Sports Bar"
   ],
   "72125494439":[
      "School",
      "School",
      "Culinary School"
   ],
   "162735832146":[
      "Hotel",
      "Hotel"
   ],
   "168777155018":[
      "School",
      "School",
      "Culinary School"
   ],
   "201503306550753":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Restaurant"
   ],
   "148930827579":[
      "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
      "Event",
      "Theatre"
   ],
   "177166092299013":[
      "Aerospace/defense",
      "Aerospace/Defense"
   ],
   "170075986343712":[
      "Local business",
      "Park",
      "Park",
      "Golf Course"
   ],
   "196487050452313":[
      "Health/beauty",
      "Health/Beauty"
   ],
   "404681091275":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "46813707682":[
      "Museum/art gallery",
      "Museum/Art Gallery"
   ],
   "52417410096":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "173866245998481":[
      "Local business",
      "Neighborhood",
      "Public Places & Attractions",
      "Apartment/Condo Building"
   ],
   "125559540801588":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Steakhouse",
      "American Restaurant"
   ],
   "21409546917":[
      "School",
      "School",
      "Dance Instruction",
      "Performing Arts Education"
   ],
   "112319308787259":[
      "Local business",
      "Bakery",
      "Japanese Restaurant"
   ],
   "119012133732":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Restaurant"
   ],
   "168648100919":[
      "Retail and consumer merchandise",
      "Clothing Store"
   ],
   "40689432989":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Sushi Restaurant",
      "Asian Fusion Restaurant"
   ],
   "204824546215995":[
      "Record label",
      "Entertainment Consultant",
      "Music Production",
      "Entertainment Service"
   ],
   "5942134076":[
      "Media/news/publishing",
      "Media/News/Publishing"
   ],
   "199770173391138":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Chinese Restaurant",
      "Seafood Restaurant"
   ],
   "10387248989":[
      "Health/beauty",
      "Health/Beauty"
   ],
   "35370009210":[
      "Health/wellness website",
      "Beauty Salon",
      "Makeup Artist",
      "Cosmetics & Beauty Supply"
   ],
   "19659469303":[
      "Shopping/retail",
      "Kitchen Supplies"
   ],
   "94130415360":[
      "University",
      "College/University"
   ],
   "43609808159":[
      "Company",
      "Company"
   ],
   "154215737954402":[
      "Local business",
      "Shopping & Retail"
   ],
   "179307775438035":[
      "Local business",
      "Community & Government"
   ],
   "5281959998":[
      "Media/news/publishing",
      "Newspaper"
   ],
   "13259856990":[
      "Museum/art gallery",
      "Museum",
      "Education"
   ],
   "115288898554295":[
      "Local business",
      "Jewelry Store"
   ],
   "102905683833":[
      "Food/beverages",
      "Food/Beverages"
   ],
   "137259562993246":[
      "Local business",
      "Government Organization",
      "Police Station"
   ],
   "8304333127":[
      "Media/news/publishing",
      "Newspaper"
   ],
   "117408098327646":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "133216873424666":[
      "Company",
      "Company"
   ],
   "212819615511497":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Cafe",
      "Bar"
   ],
   "102301474968":[
      "Bar",
      "Bar",
      "Family Style Restaurant",
      "Professional Services"
   ],
   "23087075630":[
      "Business services",
      "Shopping & Retail",
      "Business Services"
   ],
   "43581127981":[
      "Retail and consumer merchandise",
      "Electronics Store",
      "Photographic Services & Equipment",
      "Business Services"
   ],
   "204085459644179":[
      "Government organization",
      "Government Organization"
   ],
   "184398548057":[
      "Radio station",
      "Radio Station"
   ],
   "66030778436":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "117226214961950":[
      "Local business",
      "Bar",
      "French Restaurant",
      "American Restaurant"
   ],
   "111970662190414":[
      "Local business",
      "Train Station",
      "Subway/Light Rail Station",
      "Transportation Service"
   ],
   "295684530523663":[
      "Bar",
      "Bar",
      "Restaurant",
      "Social Club"
   ],
   "134989809879659":[
      "Local business",
      "Chinese Restaurant"
   ],
   "79360828514":[
      "Retail and consumer merchandise",
      "Department Store",
      "Women"      s Clothing Store",
      "Shopping Mall"
   ],
   "220295214662500":[
      "Bar",
      "Bar"
   ],
   "269432346432338":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "153561472759":[
      "Tv network",
      "TV Network"
   ],
   "99476123001":[
      "Health/beauty",
      "Makeup Artist"
   ],
   "108980342498683":[
      "Local business",
      "American Restaurant"
   ],
   "155458561155815":[
      "Church/religious organization",
      "Christian Church"
   ],
   "173543506071318":[
      "Food/beverages",
      "Food/Beverages"
   ],
   "247376308642730":[
      "Health/wellness website",
      "Medical & Health"
   ],
   "59869563396":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Performance Venue",
      "Art Gallery"
   ],
   "29531401902":[
      "Local business",
      "Concert Venue",
      "Theatre",
      "Performance Venue"
   ],
   "283424081752429":[
      "Public places",
      "Night Club"
   ],
   "198139726966453":[
      "Shopping/retail",
      "Mattresses & Bedding",
      "Furniture Store"
   ],
   "14158343106":[
      "Media/news/publishing",
      "Publisher"
   ],
   "304738169546976":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "78292498422":[
      "Sports venue",
      "Sports Venue/Stadium"
   ],
   "213200048741860":[
      "Hotel",
      "Hotel"
   ],
   "136526126403331":[
      "Government organization",
      "Government Organization"
   ],
   "45386717890":[
      "Local business",
      "Tourist Attraction",
      "Historical Place",
      "Tours & Sightseeing"
   ],
   "208178949252224":[
      "Local business",
      "Breakfast & Brunch Restaurant",
      "Bar & Grill"
   ],
   "92817028706":[
      "Internet/software",
      "Internet/Software"
   ],
   "98029424570":[
      "Health/beauty",
      "Health/Beauty"
   ],
   "10427362470":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "115735125296":[
      "Museum/art gallery",
      "Museum"
   ],
   "147571821931310":[
      "Local business",
      "Shopping District",
      "Tourist Attraction",
      "Neighborhood"
   ],
   "38502003238":[
      "Media/news/publishing",
      "Arts & Entertainment"
   ],
   "54307229494":[
      "Club",
      "Workplace/Office"
   ],
   "109637212390812":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "101034256635219":[
      "Local business",
      "Education"
   ],
   "105173906206303":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "49385786705":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Fine Dining Restaurant",
      "French Restaurant"
   ],
   "68793499001":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Professional Services",
      "Charity Organization"
   ],
   "147250751957739":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "289192763550":[
      "Radio station",
      "Radio Station"
   ],
   "166479296744410":[
      "Local business",
      "Education"
   ],
   "22933262151":[
      "Local business",
      "Shopping & Retail"
   ],
   "273099936146184":[
      "Real estate",
      "Real Estate"
   ],
   "67997232685":[
      "Retail and consumer merchandise",
      "Retail and Consumer Merchandise"
   ],
   "26576092542":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Sandwich Shop",
      "Burger Restaurant",
      "American Restaurant"
   ],
   "334528336602675":[
      "Shopping/retail",
      "Shopping & Retail"
   ],
   "112319735528":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Concert Venue",
      "Region",
      "Outdoors"
   ],
   "117332188286245":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Restaurant"
   ],
   "155869377766434":[
      "Media/news/publishing",
      "Broadcasting & Media Production"
   ],
   "220596027986153":[
      "Local business",
      "Local Business"
   ],
   "101270893265925":[
      "Local business",
      "Subway/Light Rail Station",
      "Railroad",
      "Train Station"
   ],
   "113463215353586":[
      "Local business",
      "Lounge",
      "Arts & Entertainment",
      "Bar"
   ],
   "110576459032450":[
      "Local business",
      "Bakery",
      "American Restaurant",
      "Cafe"
   ],
   "103961942986990":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Burger Restaurant",
      "Barbecue Restaurant",
      "American Restaurant"
   ],
   "29300864323":[
      "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
      "Arts & Entertainment"
   ],
   "48295469237":[
      "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
      "Arts & Entertainment"
   ],
   "265974103414598":[
      "Shopping/retail",
      "Shopping & Retail"
   ],
   "61277478605":[
      "Public places",
      "Recreation Center",
      "Public Places & Attractions",
      "Park"
   ],
   "288527347830":[
      "Radio station",
      "Radio Station"
   ],
   "13881287428":[
      "Company",
      "Business Services"
   ],
   "246934688734461":[
      "Museum/art gallery",
      "Museum/Art Gallery"
   ],
   "167949390016455":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "New American Restaurant"
   ],
   "32537282162":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "147218785328687":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Steakhouse",
      "Brazilian Restaurant"
   ],
   "131198600245354":[
      "Hotel",
      "Hotel"
   ],
   "117182708300058":[
      "Local business",
      "Cafe"
   ],
   "202236565897":[
      "Company",
      "Modeling Agency"
   ],
   "132188063464234":[
      "Hotel",
      "Hotel"
   ],
   "144603412237027":[
      "Local business",
      "Sports Venue/Stadium",
      "Sports & Recreation",
      "Food & Restaurant"
   ],
   "192663574093944":[
      "Local business",
      "Bar",
      "Restaurant"
   ],
   "175095085865160":[
      "Government organization",
      "Government Organization"
   ],
   "308276469185022":[
      "Hotel",
      "Hotel"
   ],
   "180946120405":[
      "Company",
      "Company"
   ],
   "228978783827634":[
      "Local business",
      "Japanese Restaurant",
      "Steakhouse"
   ],
   "47683628245":[
      "Radio station",
      "Radio Station"
   ],
   "187298251284725":[
      "Bar",
      "Bar",
      "Restaurant"
   ],
   "21117566782":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Non-Profit Organization"
   ],
   "131587516892795":[
      "Local business",
      "French Restaurant"
   ],
   "33963903738":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Family Style Restaurant",
      "Chinese Restaurant"
   ],
   "263148680371532":[
      "Local business",
      "Coffee Shop",
      "Bridge"
   ],
   "126245940791548":[
      "Local business",
      "Chinese Restaurant",
      "Dim Sum Restaurant"
   ],
   "53184441686":[
      "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
      "Concert Venue",
      "Sports Venue/Stadium",
      "Sports Arena"
   ],
   "123682294356645":[
      "Local business",
      "Government Organization"
   ],
   "177480462305851":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Italian Restaurant",
      "Vegetarian/Vegan Restaurant",
      "Pizza Place"
   ],
   "193382748691":[
      "Church/religious organization",
      "Religious Center"
   ],
   "226863527325560":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Japanese Restaurant",
      "Fine Dining Restaurant",
      "Vegetarian/Vegan Restaurant"
   ],
   "303511076370691":[
      "Computers/technology",
      "Web Development",
      "Web Design"
   ],
   "145702228785572":[
      "Local business",
      "Business Center",
      "Government Organization",
      "Courthouse"
   ],
   "120727317966271":[
      "Radio station",
      "Radio Station"
   ],
   "158126016796":[
      "Arts/entertainment/nightlife",
      "Event",
      "Theatre"
   ],
   "181269698586021":[
      "Education",
      "Computer Training"
   ],
   "176538189024384":[
      "Museum/art gallery",
      "Museum/Art Gallery"
   ],
   "288651434553907":[
      "Club",
      "Night Club"
   ],
   "275746105805399":[
      "Local business",
      "Liquor Store"
   ],
   "212305355450803":[
      "Restaurant/cafe",
      "Lodging",
      "New American Restaurant"
   ],
   "116084215085843":[
      "Local business",
      "DVD & Video Store",
      "Book Store",
      "Comic Book Store"
   ],
   "233380236773079":[
      "Attractions/things to do",
      "Video Games",
      "Arcade"
   ],
   "98558906864":[
      "Attractions/things to do",
      "Museum",
      "Public Places & Attractions",
      "Tours & Sightseeing"
   ],
   "367173717818":[
      "Non-profit organization",
      "Dance Instruction",
      "Performing Arts Education"
   ],
   "5768707450":[
      "Professional sports team",
      "Professional Services",
      "Sports & Recreation",
      "Arts & Entertainment"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to reveal a full list of categories, especially via FQL. I can volunteer a clever trick, though.

Facebook uses [Factual](http://www.factual.com/) to populate these categories for most pages. Their API will deliver a list of all categories in use, and is a more friendly way to deliver Facebook (or other social media) page results matching one or more categories in a geographical area. Look at their Crosswalk API.

Not sure what you're doing, but personally, I'd make Factual API calls to find the Facebook ids of the places you're interested in, then feed those ids into FQL to find the specific details your app needs about those places.