# How to get Facebook Mutual Friends Likes with category

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am working on a Android App where I need to fetch Mutual Likes for different categories (Music, Movies, Books etc). So far I am able to get the mutual likes, but I need to filter the list according to a particular category (eg movies)

My Graph API QUERY is

```
FRIEND_FB_IDxxx?fields=context{mutual_likes{name,picture.width(200).height(200).type(square)}}

FRIEND_FB_IDxxx?fields=context{mutual_likes{name,picture.width(200).height(200).type(square),category}}

//i am trying to do something like this, but I am not sure if this is possible with the GRAPH API
FRIEND_FB_IDxxx?fields=context{mutual_likes{category(Musician/Band)}}
```

this link provides all the categories of Page, Can I use this to fetch the list?
[Facebook Pages — Authoritative List of Categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216648/facebook-pages-authoritative-list-of-categories/8576572#8576572)

If this is not possible with the Graph api, 
then should I fetch the JSON Response, stuff it into Java List and then Filter the Categories? But this seems stupid to process large data.

Any Suggestion of how do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot filter on Like category, at least there's no official documentation that I know of. I think you'll need to live with the applciation-based filtering so far, until Facebook introduces general filtering capacities for the Graph API.